# Daily Life of Clinical Psycologist

Tags: clinical-psychology, writing

What is the daily routine of a clinical psycologist? Granted, schedules fluctuate and people have different personal lives. I am writing a story that has a character with the same occupation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about cognitive science.

Comment: Hi Nemo, at CogSci we discuss scientific studies or topics that can be explained with scientific research. Unfortunately this is no place for workplace behavior. I don't know if [workplace.se] will allow this question, but you could always check [worldbuilding.se].

Comment: Personally, I think discussion of the applied practice of psychologists whether they be educational, organisational, clinical, etc should be on topic. That said, this question seems a bit vague and broad.